# Disable translation for special controllers

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate

is there any possibility to disable the language translator for a controller?
This example controller only delivers images.

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->translator ???
```

TIA
Matt

Comment: How are you initializing the translator? By setting it in Zend_Registry?

Comment: translator initializing in bootstrap with "registerPlugin" and by using Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you initialize the translator in bootstrap by including it in the Zend Registry, maybe you could just unset the `Zend_Translate` entry in it from the `init()` method of the controller, which is called after the bootstrap.

Unsetting a single value in the `Zend_Registry` [is not so trivial](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Registry-how-to-unset-a-single-variable-in-the-registry-td3236086.html). In short, you need to do something like this:

```
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
unset($registry['Zend_Translate']);
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: My problem here is, that I receive error "no translation for language xx avaible". Putting an empty translation file for that controller has done it, but I thought it could be done much simpler?

Comment: It could be that some element of your site already registered the translator for using it before you have unset the reference to it in the `init` method of the controller. Maybe unsetting it a bit earlier (for instance in a controller plugin) could do the trick.

Comment: THANKS! I've turned it "off" in the LanguagePlugin (Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract) if the modulename / controllername is "image". Thanks.